# Double integral over circular surface

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

*I've decided to finish my education through completing my last exam (I've been working for 5 years). The exam is in multivariable calculus and I took the classes 6 years ago so I am very rusty. Will ask a bunch of questions over the following weeks and I love you all for helping me.*

I got this from an exam answer:

$$\iint\limits_S F\cdot dS=\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\le1}F(x,y,2)\cdot (0,0,1)dxdy= 2\pi$$

I presume it goes

$$..\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\le1}F(x,y,2)\cdot (0,0,1)dxdy=\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\le1}0x+0y+2dxdy=\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\le1}2dxdy=..$$

**But how to think for that last step to get $2\pi$**? I have never solved a double integral over a joined surface like that. I relise that $2\pi$ is a full circle, but I would like to know exactly why I get that answer in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using polar coordinates 
$$\begin{gather}
\begin{cases}x=\rho\cos{\varphi}, \\
y=\rho\sin{\varphi},
\end{cases}\end{gather}$$
$$\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\leqslant {1}}2\ dx\,dy=2\int\limits_{0}^{1} \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{\rho} \ d{\varphi} \, d{\rho}=2\pi.$$

Comment: Oh I know polar coordinates! That made it clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

The double integral $\displaystyle \iint_C 1 dxdy$ over the disk $C=\{x^2+y^2\leqslant 1\}$ gives the area of the disk,  which is $\pi$, while the factor of $2$ gives the $2$ in $2\pi$.